# Developer script exception -System.SObjectException: Invalid field MyField__C for OBJECTNAME

Tags: apex, exception, fields, before-trigger, invalid

I have written following code in an `Apex Trigger`

```
List<Setting__c> settings = new List<Setting__c>();
settings = [select name,field_api__c,Type__c from Setting__c where Object_Label__c = 'Lead'];

for(Lead objLead: Trigger.New){
    for(Setting__c objSetting: settings){    
        if(objLead.get(objSetting.field_api__c)!=null &&  
        objLead.get(objSetting.field_api__c)!='') **##THIS_LINE_CAUSE_AN_ERROR**
        {
            //MY BUSINESS LOGIC
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following error sometimes when I am trying to access fields from other Installed packages-like - `Namespace__Field__c`

**Error :**

> Developer script exception from CLIENT : MyApp.MyTrigger :
>   MyApp.MyTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by:
>   System.SObjectException: Invalid field Namespace__Field__c for Lead
>   (MyApp)

Comment: I have seen this error when the package's field is only valid for vX.0 and you've upgraded the package to VY.0 where Y > X.

Answer (score 2):

I know of a way you could prevent these errors occurring - you could use the map returned from a `Describe` call to see if the key is present.

[This](http://devforce.co/apex-tip-check-if-field-exists-on-sobject/) blog shows how to do it:

Here is the method you'd call:

```
public static boolean hasSObjectField(String fieldName, SObject so){
    return so.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet().contains(fieldName);
}

I'd probably cache this map just before your `for` loop.
```

So your loop could look like this:

```
for(Setting__c objSetting: settings){
   if (!hasSObjectField(objSetting.field_api__c, Lead){
       continue;
   }
   if (String.isBlank(objLead.get(objSetting.field_api__c))){
       continue;
   }
   //business logic
}
```

Comment: That will prevent my whole Business Logic for my field, I dont want to prevent it. My Map contain that field, but Why is it giving me an error, and how to resolve that so that field can be used in my Business Logic rather than preventing the whole IF BLOCK code from executing.

Comment: The `continue` statement will only prevent this current iteration of the block from executing. And since the field is giving an error as indicated by the `hasSObjectField` method, then you don't want to be attempting to access this field - it's going to error.

Comment: I dont want "Continue" without this field either.  ... My problem is "I can see this field in my Object then Why I am not able to access this field ?"

Comment: If you are using a trigger handler and the object is defined `with sharing` then depending on who triggers the update, sharing settings will apply. So check this and also check all your profile access settings for this field - it could be as simple as field visibility.